# Logon Local User In Windows Server Without Password Inside Active Directory

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2

I Just made a new windows 2012 r2 server and joined it to the domain. I've been asked to create a local user without password inside that server. I keep getting "The password does not meet the password policy requirements. Check the minimum password Lenght, Password complexity and password history requirements" every time I try to make the new user.
How can I achieve that?
Regards

Comment: Probably simpler to unjoin the server from the domain, change the policy, and create the local account with the blank password that is not compliant with the security policy, then re-join the server to the domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok found it, in the domain, make a group policy called no password and apply it only to that computer server, then edit it and go into computer configuration -> windows settings -> security settings -> account policies -> password policy.
Edit minimum password lenght and set it to zero.
Run gpupdate /force on the server and then you are able to generate local users without password.